# Clear data from getElementById innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
```

Is there anyway that I can remove everything the code above put between two HTML tags?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly. What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, yes! Just like that

Comment: This question was wrongly closed with a link to a different question (clearing the content of a div). This question (removing HTML markup from contents of an element) is answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather you want to remove the text between the `<h1>` and the `</h1>`. Simple:

```js
const test = document.getElementById('test');
const child = test.firstChild;
child.innerHTML = "";
```